# Ошибка с discord.py. RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, discord.py, event-loop

Проблема в следующем - я пишу дискорд бота, и время от времени при его запуске через .bat, вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 563, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 306, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(gateway)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 132, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 769, in _ws_connect
    raise WSServerHandshakeError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.WSServerHandshakeError: 503, message='Invalid response status', url=URL('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=6&compress=zlib-stream')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\korao\Desktop\BOT\bot.py", line 99, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in connect
    ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, resume=True, session=self.ws.session_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000021D9FDA6200>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\korao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`
```

Из того, что я предпринимал - проверял галочки "PRESENCE INTENT" и "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT", менял токен бота. После смены токена проблема иногда уходила, но стоило мне что-то подправить в коде - сразу же возвращалась. Иногда даже без изменений кода она возвращалась.

Вопрос в следующем - как это исправить?

Comment: перепроверил. Да, только что он запустился, решил ещё раз запустить, ничего не менял в коде, и опять вылезла ошибка

Answer (score 0):

У вас код локального сервера 503. Это означает, что бот не может обработать какой-то из ваших запросов.